# Please provide a link to the correct XSL template for _POST_FLAT_FILE_PRODUCT_DATA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Could someone please post a link to the correct XSL template for _POST_FLAT_FILE_PRODUCT_DATA?

I can't find it anywhere on Amazon.

It's the one that has the fields like "bulletpoint", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess... you're probably looking for an Excel (XLS) template to submit products to Amazon using the _POST_FLAT_FILE_LISTINGS_DATA_ feed type.

Your Seller Central account has a wizard guiding you to a template download for your specific product category.

Please note that all uploads will have to happen in CSV format, you will have to convert them to and from XLS if you wish to use Excel for this.

Comment: I was trying to use XML to format the uploads but I switched over to flat files because the XML wasn't working. It's working for me now.